# Não consigo executar o servidor do MySQL Workbench 5.2

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando conectar ao servidor do MySql Workbench 5.2 CE para abrir um projeto em Ruby. Porém não consigo conectar ao servidor (local). Aparece o seguinte erro: **Can't connect to MYSQL on '127.0.0.1' (10061)**. Já procurei alguns tutoriais, mas nada foi eficaz.

Comment: É windows? ja viu se o serviço do mysql está sendo executado?

Comment: essa mensagem de erro ocorre normalmente quando o serviço mysql não está em execução. Procure no "painel de controle -> serviços". Na lista de serviços, procure por "mysql". Provavelmente deve estar parado. Apenas inicie o serviço (start)

Answer (score 1):

Cara, pelo que pesquisei aqui, parece que o erro retorna quando o mysql não está rodando dê uma olhada se o serviço do mysql está de pé...

`service --status-all` lista todos os serviços no linux

`net start` lista os serviços no windows

Answer (score -1):

Se você tiver o WampServer instalado no Windows, ative o serviço do MySQL.
Clique no ícone do `Wamp> MySQL> Opções do Serviço> Iniciar`.